# How to query in Mysql Index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I created a index of my employees Name. 
But know I don´t know how to query that index, how do I query an Index?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM employees

or if you are using PHP

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees");

Comment: So I don´t need to manual insert the Index name in any query?

Comment: Make user you index is set to AUTO INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but once you create the index mySQL should automatically consult it whenever it can. If you tack on the `EXPLAIN` keyword to the beginning of the query mySQL will output how it *plans* to execute your statement, including which indexes it will use.

The vast majority of the time you do not need to explicitly tell mySQL which index to use, but you *can* using [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

eg:

```
mysql> explain select * from derp_users where user_name LIKE 'user';
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | derp_users | range | user_name     | user_name | 98      | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```